# frequency plot for binned data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have binned the data to various size and would like to make a facet frequency plot for each species for a given range of petal length(a histogram for each size bin something like in the attached pic).

```
library(ggplot2) 

br = seq(1,6,by=0.4)

df1 = iris

df = as.data.frame(with(df1, table(spe = df1$Species, 
                                   pl =cut(df1$Petal.Length, br, include.lowest = TRUE))))

ggplot(df, aes(x = pl, y = Freq)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image: desired plot]

How can I do this? I am having issue with setting the x axis as I want it continuous and plot it binned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach with `facet_wrap`. We can use `str_replace_all` from `stringr` to improve the appearance of the axis labels.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
ggplot(df, aes(x = pl, y = Freq, fill = spe)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x)
    str_replace_all(x, regex(c("[\\(\\[]" = "", "," = " - ", "\\]" = "")))) + 
  facet_wrap(.~spe, ncol = 1) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

An alternative approach would be to use `geom_histogram`:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Petal.Length, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_histogram(color = "white", bins = 20) + 
  facet_wrap(.~Species, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to make the x axis continuous and not binned?

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, but why not just use `geom_histogram`? Then you have much more control.

Comment: Yes, and it saves you from having to mess with the x-axis labels. Take a look at my edit.